# Print ASCII table without loop

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

I just had an interview and I have been asked a question: How would you print all the ASCII table characters without using a loop. The language doesn't matter.

Comment: Unwrap the loop?
 `Console.WriteLine("\0x00"); Console.WriteLine("\0x01"); ... Console.WriteLine("\0xFF");`

Comment: Or *hide* the loop (if *without loop* means *without explicit loop*): `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable.Range(0, 255).Select(x => (char) x)));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only method for doing so that comes to my mind is by using **recursion** instead of loops. An algorithm for doing this will be something like:

```
void printASCII(int i){
    if(i == 128)
        return;
    print(i + " " + ((char)i) + "\n");
    printASCII(i + 1);
}
```

You should call the previous function using:

```
printASCII(0);
```

This will print the complete ASCII table, where each line contains the index followed by a space and the actual ASCII character.

I don't think you can find any other way to do so, specially that it clearly says:

> The language doesn't matter

This usually means that the question is about an algorithmic idea, rather than being specific for any language.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thanks for the note. Fixed.

Comment: @PiotrBryla You are welcome, and I hope you do better next time.

Answer (score 1):

Two other approaches that weren't mentioned:

The obvious:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c", 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127);
}
```

The power of two tree (probably intended by the interviewer):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int c;
#define a128 a64; a64;
#define a64 a32; a32;
#define a32 a16; a16;
#define a16 a8; a8;
#define a8 a4; a4;
#define a4 a2; a2;
#define a2 a; a;
#define a printf("%c", c++);

int main() {
    c = 0;
    a128
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's the one intended by the interviewer. Your approach is based on C++ language; many other languages does not contain a way of *defining* variables. However, it is a neat approach indeed.

Comment: He said I do not need any specific data structure.